# Why ActiveRecord use root user instead of specified one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is the code:

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'mysql',
  user: 'dev',
  database: 'dev_db'
)

class PageModel < ActiveRecord::Base
end

p PageModel.first
```

and here is the error:

```
mysql_adapter.rb:411:in `real_connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql::Error)
```

Why is it trying to connect as root?

MySQL `dev` user exists, has no password and has full access to `dev_db` database.

Tried to connect through both TCP and unix socket, same error.

`DataMapper` connections works just well.

```
$ gem list |grep mysql
mysql (2.8.1)
$ gem list |grep activere
activerecord (3.2.9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct key is `:username`, not `:user`.